# Why is there a white bar below the ActionBar in my activity?

Tags: android

I have an actionbar with custom size so it is shorter:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="fabCustomSize">70dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

It was working fine, but after switching to Material theme, there is a white bar below the Actionbar (it is like if the activity is using the default actionbar size instead of custom one to match the parent).

[image: Example of white bar below the Actionbar]

Here is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.VsiNalogiActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/svetlo_modra1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    ...

</HorizontalScrollView>   


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `<item name="actionBarSize">48dp</item>` in your app theme.

Add in your layout a `Toolbar`:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         .../>
```

in your code use:

```
    val toolbar: Toolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

and use a Theme with `.NoActionBar` like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Before and after:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have that on purpose there, i want my Actionbar to be shorter than the usual height.

Comment: The default is 56dp

Comment: Yes, but that is still to high, i need it less. I am wondering why did it stop working after i switched to material theme.